# Calling function from input variable

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, input

```
def function1(arguments):
    print("Function 1",arguments)

def function2(arguments):
    print("Function 2",arguments)

userInput = input()
```

Is it possible for the user to enter a function and arguments and for said function to run. eg the user enters function2("Hello World")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you can always use `eval` to make this work but for reasons eval is evil, it is better to use a dictionary call back mechanism, notably

You can create a dictionary to bind the function with the names and call them with appropriate parameters

```
call_backs = {'function1': function1, 'function2': function2}
```

assuming you provide an input as follows `function2, "Hello World"`,

You first need to split the data `userInput = userInput .split(',')` and pass it onto the callback function via the dictionary

```
call_backs[userInput[0]](userInput[1])
```